# replace WASD keys navigation with VR tracked controllers a-frame

Tags: aframe, oculus, webvr, htc-vive

I've developed an a-frame scene in a different location to where I will be able to use a headset (either oculus or HTC).

Is the tracked controller functionality built into aframe 0.7.0?

Is there code I need to add to detect these controllers and replace the desktop WASD navigation with the tracked controllers? I don't need any hands to be visible I just need to achieve the up/down/left/right movement in space.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Don McCurdy's [aframe-extras](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras) includes a component called `universal-controls` that I highly recommend. Specifically there is a `gamepad-controls` component that may do exactly what you're looking for right out of the box.

If not, `universal-controls` supports extending the main component with "custom" controllers. The ability to do so is lightly documented on the repository page, but it's pretty straightforward. I'm working on one for the GearVR controller that responds to *pressing* the GearVR trackpad to achieve movement. I still need to work on getting backward movement, but you can find my work so far [at Github](https://github.com/stlewis/aframe-experiments/blob/master/components/universal-gearvr-controls.js).

Once you've developed your own custom controller, (or decided to use mine, or whatever), you attach it to your scene's camera, like this:

```html
<a-entity 
         id='scene-camera'
         camera="userHeight: 1.6" 
         position='24 1.6 14'  
         universal-controls='movementControls: universal-gear-vr, keyboard;' 
         universal-gearvr-controls>
```

Things to note from above: Rather than the default setting, (which will attempt to load all movement controls schemes that are available), I'm telling the `universal-controls` component to use my custom component, by giving it's name in the `movementControls` parameter. Notice that I leave off 'controls' from the name though. That's because `universal-controls` adds that back later. With that said, I also attach my custom component to the camera, which must be done so that `universal-controls` can find and use it.

A quick note though, on enabling backward movement, if that's something you're interested in. I've already done it by hacking around with the original WASD movement script. You can take a look at [what I did](https://github.com/stlewis/aframe-experiments/blob/master/components/controller-movement.js) if you'd like to see that.